# Width and MaxWidth default and runtime values

Tags: wpf

In definition of FrameworkElement properties Width and MaxWidth default value is the same

```
(double)1.0/(double)0.0
```

But at runtime Width has NaN, whereas MaxWidth - Infinity. What differences between properties lead to such result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stray photons, maybe :)?

If you take a look on `Double.NaN` definition you'll see... surprise:

```
public const double NaN = (double) 1.0 / (double) 0.0;
```

And since it's a constant odds are good you are seeing it in `Width` definition. Whereas definition of `MaxWidth` is indeed 1/0 but another one.

That being said, you can define the same property with default value of `Double.NaN` and Reflector will say it's `1.0/0.0`.

PS: Glad to see you here :).